# owlCarousel not calculating height in accordion on page resize

Tags: accordion, owl-carousel

I am using owlCarousel inside an accordion. Every thing is fine until i resize the window.

After resizing if the accordion was already opened it looks perfect but if it was closed during resize the carousel height goes to 0.

I have tried to use `.refres()` method of owl carousel but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/smashingboxes/OwlCarousel2/issues/531).

The solution was given by [ses](https://github.com/ses) & improvised by [tofumedia](https://github.com/tofumedia)

As ses quoted:

> OWL start for the JS Accordion, and need a resize refresh

**JS:**

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    margin: 0,
    responsiveClass: true,
    nav: false,
    dots: true,
    items: 1,
    responsive: {
        0: {
            items: 1
        },
        600: {
            items: 1
        },
        1000: {
            items: 1
        }
    }
});

$("#accordion").accordion({
    heightStyle: "content",
    header: ".accordionHeadline",
    collapsible: true,
    active: 0,
    beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
    }
});
```

Or a more reliable solution which supports IE:

```
$("a[data-toggle='tab']").on('shown', function () {
    var evt = document.createEvent('UIEvents');
    evt.initUIEvent('resize', true, false,window,0);
    window.dispatchEvent(evt);
});
```